# Touchscreen click behaves as if ctrl is pressed - Ubuntu 16.04 - eGalaxTouch

Tags: shortcut-keys, touchscreen

I'm having this weird issue, after I Alt-Tab between stuff the touch screen click behaves as if Ctrl is pressed, to be more precise, when clicking on links in webpages they open in new tabs. It's not browser related as it happens in other apps too.

If I press and release Ctrl before using the touchscreen it works as intended until I Alt-Tab again.

Touchpad or mouse clicks work normally, it's only the touchscreen "click" that has an issue.

I just reinstalled Ubuntu so I know it was happening on a fresh install too.

In case it helps:

```
xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC7910-1018-13.00.02 id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M325                             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: I have the same bug. I have to first press and release Shift (otherwise it works as if it was pressed) and then Ctrl. My xinput list has `Wacom Co.,Ltd. Pen and multitouch sensor Finger touch` and then the same thing with `s/Finger touch/Pen stylus/` This shows that it's a generic Linux/XOrg bug with multitouch devices, because my Wacom pen signal comes from the same controller and does not show the bug.

Comment: By the way, I'm on Ubuntu 17.10 and kernel 4.13. I will try the 18.04 daily build on a USB stick and report my findings.